# Expected value in a joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, multiple-integral

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with joint density function
$$ f(x,y)=0.25$$ for $$0 \leq x \leq 2$$ and $$x-2 \leq y \leq x$$
What's $$E[X^3Y]$$

The solution is $$ 0.25  \int_{0}^{2} \! \int_{x-2}^{x} x^3yf(x,y) \,dy\,dx$$

Can I switch to $dxdy$?

$$ 0.25  \int_{0}^{2} \! \int_{y}^{2} x^3yf(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$+$$ 0.25  \int_{0}^{2} \! \int_{-2}^{y+2} x^3yf(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$

The result is different.

Comment: Sorry for wasting people's time. I can't get the same result, because I am not cautious enough. Anyway, I decided that don't delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch the order of integration you get $\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{y\vee 0}^{y+2} x^{3}yf(x,y)\ dxdy$ where $y \vee 0 $ is the maximum  of $y$ and $0$.  Now see if you get the same answer. [Split the intergal as $\int_0^{2}\int_y^{y+2} x^{3}y\ dxdy +\int_{-2}^{0}\int_0^{y+2} x^{3}y\ dxdy $].